# uitextfield unexpected menu when using apple pencil on ipad

Tags: swift, ipad, uitextfield, apple-pencil

I'm making drawing app.
it has a lot of features.
then one of feature is to write text memo by using textfield.
when i use uitextfield with apple pencil it shows unexpected menu? inputaccessoryview? on left side.
when i don use apple pencil it doesn't show.

like this.

[image]

what is this?

i want to hide it.

is it possible?

i don't know this situation.

please help

Comment: That's just the tool palette, it appears by default whenever you use Apple Pencil

Comment: Can I hide this palette?

Comment: @aheze I forgot mention

Comment: Can I hide or show,control something by swift?